# How to release file handle by aspnet_wp.exe

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Service hosted in IIS, this service generates an xml file using the following code:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Batch));
using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTPDirectoryPath"] + "\\" + bundle.Name.Replace("dat", "xml")))
{
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, batch);
    textWriter.Close();
}
```

After the XML file is written on the disk, if I try to change the content of the file OR if I try to delete the file, I get the error message that the file is being used by another process, close all programs using the file. I downloaded an app called "ofview" which shows which process holds a handle on the file and is locking it. It shows that aspnet_wp is holding the lock on the XML file. ofview allows me to release this handle, then I can change the file or delete it.

My question is: how can I release the handle programmatically, once I am done writing the file in my code? Am I missing something? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think the problem is in the IIS - we were using Enterprise Library Caching block, and it suffered from the same problem - the log files couldn't be appended to, and dozens new files were created (really frustrating). So we switched to log4net which doesn't have this issue. Try looking into different methods to lock the file - look into log4net code if you have the time... btw, what IIS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you have just the code you posted, the file handle is actually released immediately after you call `textWriter.Close()` - try putting this same code by itself in a dummy project and step through the execution.  You should receive an error when trying to delete the file just before `textWriter.Close(`) is called, but should be able to delete the file right after `textWriter.Close()`.

Is there any other I/O in your service?

**EDIT**

Not sure whether this would help, but you could try flushing the stream before the close call:

```
serializer.Serialize(textWriter, batch);
textWriter.Flush();
textWriter.Close();
```

Comment: I used the same code in a console app and stepped thru & there were no issues. I can delete the file after the Close is called. If I try deleting before Close, it gives the error that another process has a handle on it. Ofcourse since this was a console app aspnet_wp has nothing to do with it.

Comment: On the WCF Service, I added Flush and then called Close, did not make any difference. Still I have the same issue. 

Yes I do have more I/O in the service. The service writes 3 files in this manner. I cant delete anyone of them since aspnet_ws has a handle on it.

Comment: Granted the test is in a console app and the problem is in aspnet_wp, but it's still the same code and the same engine that's executing it. If I were you I would create a dummy service with just the above code. If you really think the code you provided is where the problem is, your simplified / dumbed down service should yield the same difficulty without the rest of the complexity of your current service. Another thing you can do is send back to back identical requests to your service - if your first request did not close the file properly, the second request won't be able to access the file.

Comment: And if that's the case, then your second request should result in a FaultException.